# How To Do DataBinding Before ModalPopUp Control Extender Code Execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, modalpopupextender

I have `GridView` and `Button` controls nested inside a `Panel`.

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelPopUp" runat="server">

    <asp:gridview ID="gvSource" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    </asp:gridview>
    <asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" Text="Close" /> 

</asp:Panel>
```

I want to have this GridView appear as PopUp while I trigger my AJAX `ModalPopUp Extender` control

```
<act:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnMock" PopupControlID="PanelPopUp" OkControlID="OKButton">

</act:ModalPopupExtender>
```

This popup is triggered to this button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMock" runat="server" Text="Process" OnClientClick="document.getElementById('btnProcess').click();"/>
```

There is also another button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnProcess" runat="server" Text="" Style="visibility:hidden;" 
        onclick="btnProcess_Click" />
```

This button event handling (in server side):

```
protected void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Basically populating data and bind it to GridView 
}
```

My situation:

1. ModalPopUp TargetControl **doesn't trigger server side event**
2. So the there is no point handling **the event of `TargetControlID`** (`btnMock`) as it will never get to be executed
3. So I create another button `btnProcess` which has the event handled
4. The event is actually **performing databinding to `gvSource`**
5. The `btnMock` is the target control of the modal extender and also trigger the execution of `btnProcess`
6. However it doesn't work in my desired order. So `btnMock` **will display popup first** then only **have the `btnProcess` click**ed.

My question:

> Is it impossible to perform databinding during modal pop up controller execution? This workaround I tried using hidden button is not currently working in a proper order. Can anyone advise on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hide popup trigger button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMock" runat="server" Text="" Style="visibility:hidden;"  />
```

show another button and it will be the model popup control button and you need to handle click event like below.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnProcess" runat="server" Text="Process" onclick="btnProcess_Click" />

protected void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Basically populating data and bind it to GridView 


    ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
}
```

Comment: working super great. thx. I missed that `Show()` method. haha